# how do I call zgrep in windows cmd line

Tags: windows, cygwin

I've added the my cygwin\bin path to Path already but when I type in zgrep in cmd line, it says "zgrep is not recognized as an internal or external command..."

But when I do it within the cygwin cmdline, it works.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

`zgrep` is a Unix shell script, rather than an executable. Cygwin's bash shell knows how to run it, but Windows' cmd.exe doesn't. Hence you need to tell cmd.exe to invoke it through bash, like so: `bash zgrep`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `bash.exe` in your path, you can type `bash.exe /path/to/zgrep` as zgrep is actually a shell script that needs a shell interpreter.